# Calculate size of a windowed matrix

Tags: combinatorics, matrices, permutations

I was given the following problem:

> Given a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$, calculate the shape of a new matrix $B$ that is a sliding window view of $A \in \mathbb{R}^{48 \times 1536}$ with step $s$.

This is a little confusing by saying, but here's an example:

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\ \hline
 5 & 6 & 7 & 8\\ \hline
 9 & 10 & 11 & 12\\ \hline
 13 & 14 & 15 & 16\\ \hline
\end{array}
$$\bigg\downarrow$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
 1 & 2 \\ \hline
 2 & 3 \\ \hline
 3 & 4 \\ \hline
 5 & 6 \\ \hline
 6 & 7 \\ \hline
 7 & 8 \\ \hline
 9 & 10 \\ \hline
 10 & 11 \\ \hline
 11 & 12 \\ \hline
 13 & 14 \\ \hline
 14 & 15 \\ \hline
 15 & 16 \\ \hline
\end{array}

Original matrix has shape $4\times4$, and the transformed matrix with $s=2$ has shape $12\times2$. It is a little confusing for me to get the final number of rows in the transformed matrix because it doesn't seem to be related to the step size directly.

I've made some examples manually, like: matrix $[5\times4]$ with step size=$2$ generates shape $10\times2$, but same matrix with step size=$3$ generates $10\times3$ too. Some guidance is very welcome!

Comment: Formatting note: For $n\times m$ use `$n\times m$`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with this sliding-window idea, but it appears the if the matrix has has shape $n\times m$, so that there are $m$ entries in a row, and the step size is $s$, then there will be $m-s+1$ steps per row, because the first element of the step can be in any of columns $1$ through $m-s+1$.  Then there will be $n(m-s+1)$ steps in all, and the resulting matrix will have shape $$n(m-s+1)\times s$$  For $n=5,m=4,s=3$ we get $10\times 3$ as in your example.

Comment: Shape $n \times n$ you mean a square matrix? I'd like to know if it also applies to the case of 48 rows x 1536 columns with a step = 512.

Comment: @joann2555 That was a typo.  I'll fix it.

Comment: Hmm... thanks for fixing it but it doens't apply if $n = 5$, $m = 4$ and $s = 2$. According to your equation, the output would be $30$ but the real one is $10$ also.

Comment: Actually, you would get $5(4-2+1)=15$.  If you add one more row, say $17,18,19,20$ to your first example, you will get $3$ more steps, namely $(17,18),(18,19),(19,20)$ which together with the $12$ you already have, makes $15$.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry. It's 15 indeed.I guess the correct formula doesn't require the multiplication by $s$, right?

Comment: There isn't a multiplication by $s$.  It the shape of the matrix.  It has $s$ columns.

Comment: Did this answer solve your problem?  If so, please accept it by clicking the check mark, so it leaves the unsolved queue.